# IKsPropertySet interface is not supported in IMFMediSource

Tags: directshow, video-capture, ms-media-foundation, wdm

I am porting my Direct Show camera based SDK to MFT. In my old code I have  KSProxy interface like IksTopolgy,IKsControl and IKsProperty .

IksTopolgy,IKsControl is used to enumerate the property set and IKsProperty  to get/set the property value.
Now I was trying to same in new code.I am able to enumerate the property i.e following code is supported in MFT.

```
CComPtr<IKsTopologyInfo> ksTopology = NULL;
hRet = m_pMediaSource->QueryInterface(&ksTopology);
```

But IKsProperty interface which is used  to get/set the property value is not working returning E_NOINTERFACE.

```
 hRet = m_pMediaSource->QueryInterface(&pKsPropertySet);
```

is failing.I dont understand why this is not supported in m_pMediaSource
Please suggest how to get/set the properties value.

Comment: I don't think media sources are not supposed to support `IKs*` interfaces, even though you found some are supported.